# Криво запускается код Monkeyrunner

Tags: android, python

Есть код. Он берет ссылки из файла и запускает их на устройстве. Проверяем тем самым сайт. Вот этот участок кода

```
import os
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

def record():
with open('C:\op\link.txt') as  inp :
    try:
        temp = inp.readlines()
        url = temp.pop(0)
        with open ('C:\op\link.txt','w') as out:
            for i in temp :
                out.write( i)
            return ''.join(['', url] )
    except IndexError:
        print('1')
PACKAGE = 'com.android.browser'
ACTIVITY = '.BrowserActivity'
COMPONENT = PACKAGE + "/" + ACTIVITY
URI = record()
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(0.1,'1777cda7')
device.startActivity(component=COMPONENT, uri=URI)
```

То запускается, то не запускается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Без уточнений деталей проблемы, рискну предположить, что не успевает запустится за время указанное в аргументе метода **waitForConnection**. Попробуйте увеличить величину таймаута.